# Treat the prev element in JavaScript array when creating object dynamically

Tags: javascript, object

I want to do something like:

```
 var arr = []
 for var(i=0;i<x;i++){
   arr.push{ get num(){return this.previousArrayElement.num + randomNumber}}
 }
```

how can I treat "previousArrayElement"?

Comment: What have you done so far?  What errors do you get when you try your code?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure this is what you want. Expected output shown is not valid syntax and details provided are very open to interpretation

```
 var arr = []
 for (var i=0; i < x; i++){
   var num = i > 0 ? arr[i-1].num : 0;
       num= num + randomNumber; // is this an existing variable? 
   arr.push({ num: num}); // used object with property `num` based on example `previousArrayElement.num `
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just trying to create an array of size x containing numbers in order of size and separated by randomNumber intervals?  Something like this would work:

```
 var x = 100;
 var arr = [0]
 for (i=1; i<x; i++) {
   arr.push( arr[i-1] + Math.random() );
 }
```

Note that by starting the array out with an initial value (index 0) and beginning your iteration with the second value (index 1) you don't have to worry about accessing the 0-1 element at the first iteration.

I hope that helps!

Comment: No, because we started out with an array containing the initial 0-index value (in this case also 0).  If we want exactly 100 values in the array we will get that by pushing 99 values after that initial one.  This way saves having to use conditional expression that you used, though that's also a perfectly valid way to do it.

Comment: yup, my bad... didn't notice arr=[0]

Comment: S'ok :)  I did make some leaping assumptions about what he was trying to accomplish with this bit of code, e.g. the "randomNumber" variable.